# Syntax for mailto

Tags: html, email

When using a mailto link like this:

```
<A HREF="mailto:user@domain.dom" TITLE="Subject">Link Text</A>
```

is it possible to set the FROM: address?

UPDATE:  I forgot to mention that I have a captive audience who will ALL be using IE8 and Outlook.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is no.

`mailto` will open your prefered email client. The from address will be set up in your mail client.

Given that your users will all be using Outlook, their email address will already be the from address.

Answer (score 9):

It isn't, unfortunately - You can only specify the subject, cc, bcc and the body of the message. Check the full syntax : <strike>http://www.ianr.unl.edu/internet/mailto.html</strike> [updated](http://www.sightspecific.com/~mosh/WWW_FAQ/mailsubj.html)

For example,

```
<a href="mailto:john@smith.ee?Subject=Challenge yourself">Send</a>
```

Comment: Yep saw that link and also this one: http://www.sightspecific.com/~mosh/WWW_FAQ/mailsubj.html

Answer (score 5):

I think you're looking for the reply-to address, which is what *appears* to the recipient as the sender in 99% of email clients:

```
mailto:?reply-to=somebody@somewhere.com
```

Fancier example here:

```
mailto:terminator@thefuture.fake?reply-to=ahnold@thefuture.fake&subject=it%20verks!&message=get%20to%20the%20chopper!
```

Comment: does this actually get picked up by email clients? i've never seen this documented anywhere

Comment: Works for me when I type it into my browsers URL bar, Mac OS default mail client

Answer (score 4):

The from address is always the address that is in the email client that sends the message, so no.

Comment: Yep I get that but what I'm asking is can I override it?

Comment: no O_o in order to do that you would have to hack the mail client (e.g. outlook) and since that has nothing to do with the HTML there's really nothing like that that you can do.