# How to send an email to recipient

Tags: php, html, email

I know that there are multiple posts and questions out there on How to send an email from HTML form. But, I am having a slightly different query.

I have an HTML form, what I want is that when I click on submit, it should not show the information in a mail, but it should directly send the form information to recipients email ID. When I tried the following code:

```
<form action="mailto:dummy1@chamisplace.com" method="POST" 
enctype="multipart/form-data"
      name="EmailTestForm">

Your Name:<br>
<input type="text" size="20" name="VisitorName"><br><br>

Your Comment:<br>
<textarea name="VisitorComment" rows="4" cols="20">
</textarea><br><br>

<input type="submit" value="Email This Form">

</form>
```

It is opening a MS Outlook window with the form information. But it is not sending it automatically.

Comment: You can't directly send an email from a form like that. The most you can do is put a `mailto:` URL, look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792855/syntax-for-mailto) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto) for more information. Edit: you can probably use some Javascript that will generate a `mailto` link based on the contents of a form.

Comment: You've tagged this `php`, did you look at http://php.net/mail ?

Comment: mailto open any associated mail program either use php mail or use mailto like this mailto:dummy1@chamisplace.com?subject=abc&body=xyz

Comment: You can't send it automatically because it opens a foreign application which you can't control with html/PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use mail() function of php

```
mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_body)
```

and you have to configure ur email

```
http://stackoverflow.com/a/18185233/2535521
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$to="mailaddredd";
$from= "ownmailaddress";
$subject="Subject";
$message ="Comments";

mail($to,$subject,$message);

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using only `mailto` for your `action` and not using any PHP script you can't send it automatically because you are having your form open and send data to the users prefered email program which can't be controlled remotely as far as sending emails. That is a good thing because that would be a way to spam people without thinking/knowing about it.

If you are looking to use PHP to send an email there's tons of libraries and tutorials on this site or even searching Google.